# Angular NS_BINDING_ABORTED after window.location

Tags: angular, firefox

using angular with ngrx I have to open, **on the same page**, a URL outside my application after a backend response.
This works fine in Chrome but in Firefox I'm having a lot of request blocked with NS_BINDING_ABORTED.
I am redirecting to another angular application which by the way never get reached. Confirmed via console.log on very first instructions.

[image]

In the application, when a buttons is clicked a specific actions is dispacthed. In the subscribe of the effect linked to the response the window.location is called.

```
this.subsink.add(
      this.actions$
        .pipe(
          ofType(toreActions.REQUEST),
          filter((resp) => *somefilter*)
        )
        .subscribe((url) =>
            window.open(url, '_self');
        )
    );
```

Tried *window.location.open*, window.location.href as well, but none of them work.
I've tried other solutions such as setInterval inside the subscribe but again it does not work.

Comment: please share a minimal code stackblitz with the issue reproduced for debugging!

Comment: why not just location.href=url, or  location.assign(url)?  window.open has some checks regarding user-initiated.  Open will also create a new handle methinks...

Comment: None of the proposed solution works...